# How to deploy different bootstrap.properties to different environments with Aws Code Pipeline

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, spring-cloud, aws-codepipeline

So I have a serverless spring boot application that I currently deploy to aws using code pipeline. This spring boot application uses a bootstrap.properties file to call a cloud config server that we are using for our properties. The problem that I'm having is that I cant figure out how to get code pipeline to deploy different bootstrap.properties files for each environment that it deploys to so that I can streamline the process and have each environment access its own properties. Does anyone know if there is a way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**bootstrap-[profile].properties** allow you to load diferente variables per enviroment in combination with spring profiles active

For example

1. (default) bootstrap.properties
2. (SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=prod) bootstrap-prod.properties